# STM32 Memory Alignment unclear

Tags: stm32, memory

As I'm reading the Mastering STM32 Book, I came across this graphic describing the memory map [image]

So what I'm trying to figure out is whether my understanding of memory is wrong, or if the graphic is. It is my understanding that in the figure on the right, the 5th variable (a byte) should be at address 0x20000008. The memory addresses increase from right to left, and top to bottom. So the 1st variable would have bits 7 to 0 at 0x20000000, bits 15 to 8 at 0x20000001, so on so forth. Could someone point me in the right direction if I'm incorrect?

Comment: Is this big-endian or little-endian?

Comment: @Elliot-Alderson Little-Endian

Comment: it is a pretty bad way to show it unless there is text you didnt provide that indicates that only one of the items on the right is unaligned and the rest are aligned.

Comment: everything else on both sides is aligned.

Comment: you are correct bits 7..0 are at address 0x20000000 and 15..8 at 0x20000001.  and the 5th item is at address 0x20000008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that is not aligned is the #4 word in the right-hand diagram.

Everything else in both diagrams is aligned on natural boundaries — bytes on byte boundaries (by definition, since it's byte-addressable memory), halfwords on halfword boundaries, and words on word boundaries.

---

The thing that is really weird about the right-hand diagram is that #4 word does not occupy a contiguous set of bytes, and this may well be a drawing error. For some reason, bytes are numbered right-to-left, but the objects are packed left-to-right. I would have expected those diagrams to look more like this, in which the packing is in the same order as the byte addresses:

**Aligned**

```
     3        2        1        0
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|              word 1               | 0x20000000
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|////////| byte 3 |   halfword 2    | 0x20000004
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|              word 4               | 0x20000008
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|////////| byte 7 | byte 6 | byte 5 | 0x2000000C
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|/////////////////|   halfword 8    | 0x20000010
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

**Unaligned**

```
     3        2        1        0
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|              word 1               | 0x20000000
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| word 4 | byte 3 |   halfword 2    | 0x20000004
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| byte 5 |          word 4          | 0x20000008
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   halfword 8    | byte 7 | byte 6 | 0x2000000C
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|///////////////////////////////////| 0x20000010
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you, your diagrams are what I would've expected. All things considered this just seems like a poor example considering even the unaligned data is mostly aligned.

Answer (score 1):

That diagrams are wrong, it looks like the author could not decide whether the addresses increase from left to right or right to left, and changed his mind halfway through.

Here is my attempt, with addresses increasing left-to-right.

Aligned structure:

     `+------------+------------+------------+------------+
     | 1                                                 |
     |    LSB              word(32)               MSB    |
     | 0x20000000   0x20000001   0x20000002   0x20000003 |
     +------------+------------+------------+------------+
     | 2                       | 3          | ////////// |
     | LSB   halfword(16)  MSB |  byte(8)   | / unused / |
     | 0x20000004   0x20000005 | 0x20000006 | ////////// |
     +------------+------------+------------+------------+
     | 4                                                 |
     |    LSB              word(32)               MSB    |
     | 0x20000008   0x20000009   0x2000000A   0x2000000B |
     +------------+------------+------------+------------+
     | 5          | 6          | 7          | ////////// |
     |  byte(8)   |  byte(8)   |  byte(8)   | / unused / |
     | 0x2000000C | 0x2000000D | 0x2000000E | ////////// |
     +------------+------------+------------+------------+
     | 8                       | /////////////////////// |
     | LSB   halfword(16)  MSB | /////// unused //////// |
     | 0x20000010   0x20000011 | /////////////////////// |
     +------------+------------+------------+------------+`

Unaligned, a.k.a. packed structure:

     `+------------+------------+------------+------------+
     | 1                                                 |
     |    LSB              word(32)               MSB    |
     | 0x20000000   0x20000001   0x20000002   0x20000003 |
     +------------+------------+------------+------------+
     | 2                       | 3          | 4          >
     | LSB   halfword(16)  MSB |  byte(8)   |    LSB ... >
     | 0x20000004   0x20000005 | 0x20000006 | 0x20000007 >
     +------------+------------+------------+------------+
     > 4 (cont)                             | 5          |
     >        word(32)               MSB    |  byte(8)   |
     > 0x20000008   0x20000009   0x2000000A | 0x2000000B |
     +------------+------------+------------+------------+
     | 6          | 7          | 8                       |
     |  byte(8)   |  byte(8)   | LSB   halfword(16)  MSB |
     | 0x2000000C | 0x2000000D | 0x2000000E   0x2000000F |
     +------------+------------+------------+------------+`

Comment: That would be the big-endian interpretation, but the OP said (in a comment) that it's little-endian.

Comment: @DaveTweed [Big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big) means that the [MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_byte) would be stored at the lowest address (e.g. `0x20000000`), and the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_byte) at the highest address (e.g. `0x20000003`). My drawing is the exact opposite, it depicts the [Little-Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little) arrangement (STM32 is always little-endian), so as you can observe, LSB is at the lowest address (`0x20000000`) and MSB is at the highest address (`0x20000003`)

Comment: In that case, your drawing is simply a mirror image of mine.

Comment: @DaveTweed I chose left-to-right increasing addresses, as memory dumps are usually displayed that way. (Have you ever looked at a hexdump?) Well, perhaps it's the other way round in a right-to-left writing locale, but we are on an English language forum, discussing a textbook written in English.